# Knowledge consolidation synonyms, more colloquial

Tags: phrases, synonyms

Let's say I've finished 1st learning/studies stage out of 3 and being asked what is my motivation to proceed to stage 2 or 3. As a part of my answer I want to say that I wish to "*consolidate my knowledge*".  (*knowledge consolidation*)

Question: What are the synonyms to this phrase? I've tried to find this phrase on Google but the results are scarce, thus I feel that there is a more natural/native variant.

Answer (score 1):

[Consolidate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consolidate) means to strengthen or to combine: I guess that you want the former meaning (strengthen).

I think that's about the best option available *with that meaning*, but you could also consider **broaden**, **extend** or **build on** which, according to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broaden%20your%20knowledge%2C%20deepen%20your%20knowledge%2Cextend%20your%20knowledge%2Cconsolidate%20your%20knowledge%2Cbuild%20on%20your%20knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroaden%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeepen%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextend%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsolidate%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuild%20on%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0), are all more widely used than **consolidate**.

Comment: can I say "to deepen the knowledge"?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's better than consolidate or build on, but not as good as extend. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deepen+your+knowledge%2C+extend+your+knowledge%2Cconsolidate+your+knowledge%2Cbuild+on+your+knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeepen%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextend%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsolidate%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuild%20on%20your%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0. You could try out some ideas with NGram yourself...

Comment: I sneaked another option into my answer- broaden- which is even more common than the others.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already mentioned *extend* and *broaden* you could also consider such verbs as *advance, enhance, expand, improve, increase* and *further*, which all collocate with the noun knowledge.